# What would cause a job in a bamboo stage to not display/execute during a run?

Tags: bamboo

I have a plan that has an introductory stage meant to bail the plan early if certain prerequisites aren't met right off the bat. However when I run that plan I see the first stage but I don't see its job and aren't sure what configuration I may have overlooked that would prevent that job from executing. That job `Check1` is simply a source checkout task along with an inline script task both of which appear to be enabled as far as I can tell.

What should I look into to diagnose what's going on with this absent job?

[image: Plan Configuration]

[image: Run with Missing Job]

Answer (score 0):

What happened in this instance is apparently those runs that got a truncated stage were grabbed as I was developing the jobs in the stage and playing around with configurations. Some jobs in the queue snagged a premature state of the plan. Now that the queue flushed overnight I am seeing the expected job is running as expected.